# Residual diagnostics in MCMC -based regression models

Tags: r, bayesian, mixed-model, markov-chain-montecarlo, residuals

I've recently embarked on fitting regression mixed models in the Bayesian framework, using a MCMC algorithm (function MCMCglmm in R actually).

I believe I have understood how to diagnose convergence of the estimation process (trace, geweke plot, autocorrelation, posterior distribution...).

One of the thing that strikes me in the Bayesian framework is that much effort seems to devoted to do those diagnostics, whereas very little appears to be done in terms of checking the residuals of the fitted model. For instance in MCMCglmm the residual.mcmc() function does exist but is actually not yet implemented (ie.returns: "residuals not yet implemented for MCMCglmm objects"; same story for predict.mcmc()). It seems to be lacking from other packages too, and more generally is little discussed in the literature I've found (apart from DIC which is quite heavily discussed too).

Could anyone point me to some useful references, and ideally R code I could play with or modify?

Many thanks.

Comment: Great question. I really like Andrew Gelman's [paper](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/philosophy.pdf) with Cosma Shalizi about Bayesian model checking.

Answer (score 12):

I think the use of the term residual is not consistent with Bayesian regression. Remember, in frequentist probability models, it's the parameters which are considered fixed estimable quantities and the data generating mechanism has some random probability model associated with observed data. For Bayesians, the parameters of probability models are considered to be variable and the fixed data update our belief about what those parameters are. Therefore, if you were calculating the variance of the *observed* minus *fitted* values in a regression model, the *observed* component would have 0 variance whereas the fitted component would vary as a function of the posterior probability density for the model parameters. This is the opposite of what you would derive from the frequentist regression model. I think if one were interested in checking the probabilistic assumptions of their Bayesian regression model, a simple QQplot of the posterior density of parameter estimates (estimated from our MCMC sampling) versus a normal distribution would have diagnostic power analogous to analyzing residuals (or Pearson residuals for non-linear link functions).

Comment: This is a good answer. There may yet be answers that give useful Bayesian constructs calculated from the observed-minus-fitted residual, but this one certainly shouldn't have been downvoted.

Comment: Also, it might be worth clarifying that in the Bayesian setting you don't really have "fitted" values. You could calculate the posterior mean for a given observed input, to get the maximum a posteriori estimate of the expected value of the target variable at that input. But this would be reducing everything to point estimates, which is not usually desired if you're doing Bayesian inference.

Comment: This is why "residual" is less meanginful. Residual from what? The posterior mean value? The posterior mode value? The posterior's 42.763% quantile value? What makes any one of those a better thing to use as "the" estimate than any other?

Comment: Yes, good point and thanks for the clarification on my understanding as well.

Comment: @EMS any of those are meaningful residuals. Just because one is a Bayesian doesn't mean one can't check whether the assumptions are reflected in the data.

Comment: @Glen_b I don't see how your comment adds anything to mine. I'm a huge fan of posterior predictive checking. I'm just saying there is no singleton item that is "the" residual in Bayesian analysis the way there is one single thing that is "the" residual in e.g. Frequentist linear regression. The OP seems to be trying to shoehorn that notion of residual into a Bayesian framework.

Comment: For exact probabilistic inference (normality assumptions in place) in the frequentist setting, "residuals" would, in replications of the study experiment, be conditionally independent of the "fitted value" (or conditional mean). In the Bayes world, data aren't random, so what would be conditionally independent of what?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I don't think "fitted value" is meant to correspond to coefficients, rather to $\hat{y}$. After fitting the model, you get implied fitted 'predictions' for the target variable (the conditional mean at each of the input observations) (these are what I think are being referred to as 'fitted values'). And there is just one single vector that is equal to the observed target values minus the 'fitted values' that is "the" residual vector. There is no re-running or replicating the study experiment. Such differences in a subsequent replication would not be "residuals."

Comment: Regression in Bayesian and exact frequentist procedures is a way of estimating the conditional mean $\mbox{E}[Y|X]$, usually described by a set of model parameters. I am using the conditional mean to refer to fitted values. In frequentist statistics, there *is* a concept of repeated experiments, although we conceive of the sample size and distribution of $X$ as being fixed whereas $Y$ is random and subject to replications through repeated experimentation. That's the frequentist interpretation of probability. That's why residuals have properties of random variables, notably a density function.

Comment: @EMS it's unfortunate that you don't see it adds any value, but the notion that it's appropriate to define some kind of fit and thereby residuals (even if it's not the only possible choice), or things closely related to those notions in order to do some forms of model assessment in a Bayesian model is quite widespread. Indeed, I've seen it (definitions of and/or plots of fits and or residuals) in papers by highly-recognized names.

Comment: I still don't understand. I never said I was *against* any of that. I'm just saying that the generic term "residual" doesn't mean anything to a Bayesian. You have to specify what point estimate you're interested in, and I happened to give three different ones that could be of interest to many people in a wide variety of situations. I only brought up those specific three to illustrate that there are *many* such things one might want to consider, and the application and inference goals determine which one to look at.

Comment: @Glen_b why not try to post an answer to the problem?

Comment: Not sure teh answer was the "best" but it was the only one.

Comment: You guys are way overthinking this to a level that makes things more confusing then they need to be. At the end of the day, A bayesian regression produces some estimate of an output metric, with an uncertainty. These are the "fitted" values. Then there are the data. The differences between the data and the fitted values are the "residuals". This is stats 101, I don't care if you are a frequentist or a bayesian. Plots of residuals will tell you important things about whether the assumptions of your error structure are supported or not.